# "Because these issues are so important, give yourself partial credit toward your 15 minutes a day homework assignment" - what does this mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I understand the first part of this sentence and what partial credit is, but I cant grasp the full meaning of the entire sentence. Do I need to spend some of the 15 minutes dedicated to my homework on the mentioned important issues? or is it something else?

[Link to source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bpktEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT93&lpg=PT93&dq=%22give%20yourself%20partial%20credit%20toward%22&source=bl&ots=ciSe6kLQWd&sig=ACfU3U3bXtHd9HrYxasxOSpvMaT4_fFIPg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHmcuClpr7AhUMQUEAHRVbDL0Q6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22give%20yourself%20partial%20credit%20toward%22&f=false) (about 20 lines after bold heading **DANGEROUS ASSUMPTIONS**)

Comment: Please give us the full context. What's the situation with 15 minutes? What are "these issues"?

Comment: What does *give yourself credit* mean? What is the system?

Comment: I've added a link to the source. But having noticed that it says *...toward your 15 minutes a day homework assignment **outlined on page 84***, I think the question lacks research as well as context. Note that ***I*** don't know exactly what's ***outlined on page 84***, because ***my*** link doesn't seem to have page numbers!

Comment: (Thanks @Fumblefingers for the link.)  
 The previous page seems to be page 84, and contains a "homework assignment", that is, to spend 15 minutes a day maintaining communications with one's pregnant spouse.   
Then, on the cited page, just after the quotation, there is a list of issues that merit special attention. The author says that the expectant father may claim partial credit for his 15 minutes of communication by speaking of them. The *system* of credit is just what the author says the future dad should do.

Answer (score 1):

The book (in a light-hearted way) suggests that fathers-to-be have a "homework assignment"  (this is a metaphor) to talk to their partners about "something other than the baby" for 15 minutes a day.

The book is using the metaphor of schoolwork to talk about things that couples should do during pregnancy.

This then continues the metaphor.  "Partial credit" means you have done part of the "homework". If you deal with these issues you can cut down on the time you talk about "something other than the baby".  (or you can not deal with those issues and do the full 15 min talking about not-baby)

It is all quite light-hearted, but there is probably a serious point underlying the advice.